# How To Recursively Delete Lines Contained Specific Text Using PHP On Linux Server?

Tags: php, shell, recursion, virus

I want to search my entire Linux web server for ALL files and subdirectories containing a specific string.

If that string is found, then delete that line. I am doing this because a virus got put on my website somehow, and it adds a single line of code, so if I find that line, I can delete the virus easily.

Here is my code

```
$input = 'cd ../home/public_html
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "/pantscow.ru/d" {} \ ';
echo $input;
$output = shell_exec($input);
echo "<pre>#$output</pre>";
```

Can you tell me why this doesn't work? It just returns "#".
I had it working before a few months ago, but I forgot how to execute properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this single command to find all those php files which have that string-

```
find . -name "*php" -exec grep -H abc {} \;
```

where "abc" was the string you wanted to search.

Comment: Hey. This resulted in no results being returned, even when there are files containing the string. Additionally, I need a script that automatically deletes the line containing the partially matched string - not just finds it. Any more ideas?